# Trouble installing & using a particular npm package. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have a JavaScript application utilizing several `npm` packages without an issue. However I came across [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-dijkstra), and would like to use it in my project.

I have followed the installation and typical usage guide:

1. npm install --save-dev https://github.com/LincolnTechOpenSource/graph-dijkstra
2. Include the JavaScript file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/graph-dijkstra/dist/graph-dijkstra.js">`
3. Use the available API in the following manner:

   `var graph = new Graph();
    graph.addNode(1, {weight: 1, nType: 1});`

However I am always getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Graph is not defined

Why is graph not being defined? The npm package `graph-dijkstra` appears in my node modules so it is actually installed correctly.

[image]

I have installed and used many previous npm modules and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in this particular case. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `link` tag to `script`:

```
<script src="node_modules/graph-dijkstra/dist/graph-dijkstra.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only problem in this case is because of `link` tag you are using. You can not import js using `link` tag. To import javascript you have to use `script` tag and better if you load scripts in the end of your body.

Alternatively, you can `import` or `require` the library or script wherever you want it.